# R data frame extraction of elements

Tags: r, dataframe, frame

I have 2 dataframes and i only want the the numbers which are in both frames. I use this function:

```
CH3[CH2[,2] %in% CH3[,2],]
```

The Problem is, the data frames have a different length and this operation `CH2[,2] %in% CH3[,2]` delivers 1400 true values. I have searched for a while now but could not find a solution. If i apply it on CH3 which is 1700 long i get all appending data too which are not marked as wrong. Is there a function parameter i can use or do i need a workaround?

Edit1:

```
CH3<-read.table("unkown1.txt")
CH2<-read.table("unkown2.txt")
```

Now i only want the elements which are in both tables. I used:

```
CH3[CH3[,2] %in% CH2[,2],]
```

Which only works if CH3 is larger

Comment: The really isn't about the lengths of the data frames. In the first example, you are trying to index into `CH3` using a vector which is the length of `CH2`. So this really isn't working no matter the sizes of the data frames. When `CH3` is longer, you get incorrect results. When `CH3` is shorter, you get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

`merge` is an option, depending on exactly what you are trying to do:

```
CH2 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:20], b=1:20)
CH3 <- data.frame(a=letters[15:26], b=15:26)

merge(CH2, CH3, by=2)
```

produces:

```
   b a.x a.y
1 15   o   o
2 16   p   p
3 17   q   q
4 18   r   r
5 19   s   s
6 20   t   t
```

Another alternative is with `intersect`:

```
x <- intersect(CH2[, 2], CH3[, 2])
```

Where `x` is:

```
[1] 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

You can then do either of the following:

```
CH2[CH2[, 2] %in% x, ]
CH3[CH3[, 2] %in% x, ]
```

To get:

```
   a  b
15 o 15
16 p 16
17 q 17
18 r 18
19 s 19
20 t 20
```